# Extract comments using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to extract comments and found this code here...I am running this through Netbeans...When i ran this code it is throwing an error...

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
      Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.zomato.com/mumbai/starbucks-coffee-fort").get();
      Elements div = doc.select("div.res-review-body > div > p");
        for (Element paragraph : div) {
           System.out.println(paragraph.text());
}
}

}
```

Error Details:

java:15: unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
          Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.zomato.com/mumbai/starbucks-coffee-fort").get();

Comment: The error tells you what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Netbeans you will be certainly able to see a red color light bulb in front of this line.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.zomato.com/mumbai/starbucks-coffee-fort").get();
```

click that bulb and it will show you the options. What you are missing is a try catch block for java.io.IOException.

Edit: - By clicking on that bulb it will give you option to surround the block with try and catch.

Comment: Thanks..I used the try catch block..the code runs..but i am not getting the output..I need to check the code once again...